# Translating Sinatra syntax to Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, sinatra

Stripe API documentation provides a block of code for Sinatra

```
  payment_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create(
    amount: calculate_order_amount(data['items']),
    currency: 'usd'
  )
  {
    clientSecret: payment_intent['client_secret'],
  }.to_json
```

In other instances I devised the intent, such as:

```
  session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({[...]})
  render json: { id: session.id }
```

however in this case the following returns error `Uncaught IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client_secret string. You specified: undefined.`

```
  payment_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create({
    amount: authorisation.to_i,
    currency: 'usd',
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    description: @cart_name
  })
  render json: { payment_intent: @shop.signing_secret.to_s }
```

How should this be cast?

Comment: `render json: { clientSecret: payment_intent.client_secret}`  I'd assume.

Comment: Ended up being more litteral:  `render json: { clientSecret: payment_intent['client_secret'] }`